# Python: matplotlib: coloring lines in a random walk by jump size

Tags: python, matplotlib, random-walk, graph-coloring

I have code that generates and plots a random walk just fine. However, I want to color each line according to how big of a jump it is. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def randomwalk(N):
    x, y, bigness = np.zeros((N)), np.zeros((N)), np.zeros((N))
    for n in range(0,N):
        angle = random.random() * 2*np.pi
        jump = np.random.normal(0, 50)

        x[n] = x[n-1] + (np.cos(angle) * jump)
        y[n] = y[n-1] + (np.sin(angle) * jump)
        bigness[n] = abs(jump)      
    return x, y, bigness

x, y, bigness = randomwalk(100)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Now, if I change the penultimate line to

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=bigness)
```

Then I get a bunch of dots with the required coloring, but no lines joining them. Conversely, the "plot" function doesn't have an option for individual coloring.

I want the lines from the "plot" function, but the coloring from the "scatter" function. How do I do this?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than plotting the whole line, plot its segments with color based on bigness.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def randomwalk(N):
    x, y, bigness = np.zeros((N)), np.zeros((N)), np.zeros((N))
    for n in range(0,N):
        angle = random.random() * 2*np.pi
        jump = np.random.normal(0, 50)

        x[n] = x[n-1] + (np.cos(angle) * jump)
        y[n] = y[n-1] + (np.sin(angle) * jump)
        bigness[n] = abs(jump)      
    return x, y, bigness

def random_color(bigness):
    return plt.cm.gist_ncar(bigness/100)

x, y, bigness = randomwalk(100)

xy = zip(x,y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for start, stop, b in zip(xy[:-1], xy[1:], bigness):
    x, y = zip(start, stop)
    ax.plot(x, y, color=random_color(b))

plt.show()
```

The beautiful messy result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a `LineCollection` and color each segment by `bigness`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pairs = np.array(list(zip(x, y))).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate((pairs[:-1], pairs[1:]), axis=1)
lc = mpl.collections.LineCollection(segments)
lc.set_array(bigness)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

To specify a non-default colormap and norm, pass `cmap` and `norm` arguments to `mpl.collections.LineCollection`.